# from pmdarima.model_selection import train_test_split NOT working

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, pmdarima

I am using pmdarima to apply auto_arima in python3.7.7 . When splitting the dataset using
from pmdarima.model_selection import train_test_split

following error popups :
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pmdarima.model_selection'

Already updated packages in Anaconda, still the same error.

According to pdmarima document, it should be available:
https://alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/modules/generated/pmdarima.model_selection.train_test_split.html?highlight=train_test#pmdarima.model_selection.train_test_split

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing pmdarima package from Anaconda , and re-installing using pip.
pip install pmdarima to version 1.6.0 of this package, solved the issue.